# Debounce rx observable based on condition - RxSwift

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I use this in Kotlin to debounce based on condition:

```
// variables
private val subject_isUpdating = PublishSubject.create<Int>()
var lastClickedItem = -1


// inside onCreate
adapter_cartProducts.setOnItemClickedListener { position ->
     subject_isUpdating.onNext(position)
}


// subscribing 
        subject_isUpdating
            .debounce
            { position ->
                // here if lastClickedItem changed, no debounce
                if(position != lastClickedItem) {
                    lastClickedItem = position
                    Observable.empty()
                }
                // else if same item clicked -> debounce
                else Observable.timer(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) }
            .subscribe({ position ->
                updateOnWS(position, adapter_cartProducts.items[position])
            }, { error ->
                Timber.e(error) // printing the error
            })
```

This is the debounce selector function used from the RxJava:

```
/**
 * Returns an Observable that mirrors the source ObservableSource, except that it drops items emitted by the
 * source ObservableSource that are followed by another item within a computed debounce duration.
 * <p>
 * <img width="640" height="425" src="https://raw.github.com/wiki/ReactiveX/RxJava/images/rx-operators/debounce.f.png" alt="">
 * <dl>
 *  <dt><b>Scheduler:</b></dt>
 *  <dd>This version of {@code debounce} does not operate by default on a particular {@link Scheduler}.</dd>
 * </dl>
 *
 * @param <U>
 *            the debounce value type (ignored)
 * @param debounceSelector
 *            function to retrieve a sequence that indicates the throttle duration for each item
 * @return an Observable that omits items emitted by the source ObservableSource that are followed by another item
 *         within a computed debounce duration
 * @see <a href="http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/debounce.html">ReactiveX operators documentation: Debounce</a>
 */
public final <U> Observable<T> debounce(Function<? super T, ? extends ObservableSource<U>> debounceSelector) {
    ObjectHelper.requireNonNull(debounceSelector, "debounceSelector is null");
    return RxJavaPlugins.onAssembly(new ObservableDebounce<T, U>(this, debounceSelector));
}
```

The idea of this code, user will click on item of list, and the item will be updated on webservice when user stops clicking for 400ms or clicks another item

Is that possible to be done in RxSwift ?

Answer (score 2):

I can't say I especially like the code you presented because of its dependency on the external variable.

Here's an operator that does what you want:

```
extension ObservableType where E: Equatable {

    func throttleUnlessChanged(_ dueTime: TimeInterval, scheduler: SchedulerType) -> Observable<E> {
        return Observable.create { observer in
            let lock = NSRecursiveLock()
            var last: E?
            var lastTime: RxTime?
            return self.subscribe { event in
                lock.lock(); defer { lock.unlock() }
                switch event {
                case .next(let element):
                    let now = scheduler.now
                    let timeIntervalSinceLast = lastTime != nil ? now.timeIntervalSince(lastTime!) : dueTime
                    if element != last {
                        observer.onNext(element)
                        last = element
                        lastTime = now
                    }
                    else if timeIntervalSinceLast >= dueTime {
                        observer.onNext(element)
                        last = element
                        lastTime = now
                    }
                case .error(let error):
                    observer.onError(error)
                case .completed:
                    observer.onCompleted()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a gist complete with tests: https://gist.github.com/dtartaglia/f5b041facfdcdd64630e0cb8cfc2cc5b

Comment: sorry for not explaining the external variables. I edited the question. Can you please check it again ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the operator does what you want. Check out the test suite. I didn't have a problem with you not explaining the external variable, I have a problem with it existing at all. I'm not a fan of external/un-contained side effects inside blocks like that. I updated the operator in the gist so that it's implemented with `scan` instead of `create`.

Comment: I only have a question, you wrote throttleUnlessChanged, will it behave like debounce ? cuz what i want here is debounceUnlessChanged

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the distinction is in this case. In RxSwift, debounce already emits the most up-to-date position when the time period is up. Send me a PM on the RxSwift slack (or just ask there) and I or someone can help you out with a custom operator based on you're specifications. http://slack.rxswift.org

Answer (score 0):

I feel the flatMapLatest can be used to solve the conditional debounce needed here.

```
subject
     .flatMapLatest { position in
           if position != lastClickedPosition {
               lastClickedItem = position
               return Observable.just(position)
           } else {
                return Observable.just(position).delay(.milliseconds(300), scheduler: scheduler)
           }
     }
// Subscribe
```

I have this article on creating variable debounce using combine and RxSwift. Please check this out.
https://medium.com/dev-genius/part-1-variable-time-debounce-in-swift-30a987511c6c